# When did Clive move?

Tags: vertigo-comics, izombie-2015

At some point around [S2E7](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5178410/?ref_=ttep_ep7) of iZombie, we see Clive's house, as Blaine and Liv have to intercept a lab report.  The cast talks about it a bit, as they had never been to his house before.  Then, in [S2E18](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5270988/?ref_=ttep_ep18) Live goes to Clive's *high-rise apartment* to discuss some things about Major.

Was this move discussed within the show, or was it a writer slip up?

Comment: Is there a reason this has the comics tag? It seems to be purely about the TV show.

Comment: @OrangeDog Because at some point the moderators decided that every time you tag a question with the tv show you must also include the tag for the comics, even though this has nothing to do with the comics. Weird, but it's not the only instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first house you are talking about is not Clive's. It's Bozzio's.** Clive can be seen there because he has a date with Bozzio at that night.

Evidence:

**1. Liv and Blaine's dialogue in the morgue implies they're going to sneak into Bozzio's house, as she's the one from FBI who's handling the investigation on missing persons.**

> B : Look, I know they brought the FBI in on this missing persons case.
> Anyway, they got this lady Fed heading up the investigation, Dale
> Bozzio. Bitching name. One you'd remember. Ring any bells?
>
> L : Maybe.
>
> B : Because if we can know what she knows, we stand a chance of
> getting ahead of the curve. So, what do you say? Team up with me.

**2. When Liv and Blaine are on stake-out, you can see Clive going to the house and ringing the doorbell, and then Bozzio opening it from the inside.**

[image]
[image]

**3. The brain lab report from FBI is delivered to this house, and is addressed to Bozzio** (Since Clive wanted to do the brain check discreetly, Bozzio sent it to FBI lab).

[image]

**The second one shown in S2E18 is indeed Clive's.**

So it's not a writer slip-up.

Comment: Good catch. It's been years, and maybe I should watch the whole episode to try to figure out why I thought it was Clive's house they were breaking into, but I skimmed it yesterday to confirm that it was indeed Dale's place.